# Cannot read CLLocationDegrees from plist

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, property-list

I am having some trouble with this following `struct`:

```
struct EmployeeDetails {
    let functionary: String
    let imageFace: String
    let phone: String
    let latitude: CLLocationDegrees
    let longitude: CLLocationDegrees

    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.functionary = (dictionary["Functionary"] as? String) ?? ""
        self.imageFace = (dictionary["ImageFace"] as? String) ?? ""
        self.phone = (dictionary["Phone"] as? String) ?? ""
        self.latitude = (dictionary["Latitude"] as! CLLocationDegrees)
        self.longitude = (dictionary["Longitude"] as! CLLocationDegrees)
```

I have no *compiling errors* but, when I run the app, I get this *runtime error*:

[image: error]

It's important to say that **I am loading data from a plist**. Anyone could show me what am I doing wrong?

---

**EDIT:**

Now I am having these errors:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty clear: *you are casting a string-typed value to a `NSNumber`*.

Try this instead:

```
let latitudeStr = dictionary["Latitude"] as! String
self.latitude = CLLocationDegrees(latitudeStr)!
```

and you should do the same thing to the `"Longitude"` property as well ;)

You also may be running into *localized numbers* issues. Try this:

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.decimalSeparator = ","
numberFormatter.thousandSeparator = "."
...
self.latitude = numberFormatter.number(from: latitudeStr)!.doubleValue
```

Comment: Thanks @paulo, now I am getting another compiling errors. I just edited my question to show you.

Comment: @ArnonRodrigues As a quick fix, try to replace the `,` with `.` in your plist to see if it fixes it. You may need to use `NumberFormatter` for proper number parsing...

Comment: My mistake! The data on latitudes and longitudes were incorrect. After correction, `.plist` seems to be ok. Now I having this issue on my View Controller. Just updated my question.

Comment: You forgot to initialize your `coord` property — it's `nil`!

Comment: You mean: `var coord: EmployeeDetails = nil!` ?

Comment: I spent too much time because I was looking for answers outside, but without success. I made the `coord` `nil`. But the app keeps crashing :-/

Comment: Sorry man, you misunderstood: you need to set `coord` to something else *other* than nil. For instance, create it from the plist you mentioned in your question, etc...

Comment: Things like `var coord = EmployeeDetails(dictionary: [String : Any])` and `var coord = EmployeeDetails()` aren't working. Could you suggest me something?